# How to send data from child figure to its parent in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, parent-child, figure

I have a "main" figure in my matlab project which opens a "settings" figure.
The user can change some fields in settings figure and press "Apply" button in settings figure.
I want to send the settings data from settings figure to main figure just when the apply button is pressed.

I set apply button's callback to update settings figure's handles.output by those fields and in main figure I assigned the output to a variable while calling settings figure.

```
function apply_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  handles.output = [str2num(get(handles.precinp, 'String')) get(handles.plotcheck, 'Value')
  get(handles.stepcheck, 'Value') get(handles.speedslid, 'Value')];
  guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And this is how I open settings figure from main figure:

```
function settingsbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  handles.settingsdata = cell2mat(settings());
  guidata(hObject, handles);
```

So the assignment occurs just when settings figure is opened, but I want to do it when apply button is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `uiwait` after you create the settings dialog, and `uiresume` after the apply button is clicked. You will need to pick a figure handle to wait on. A logical choice is the figure handle corresponding to the settings dialog (see the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html)). This will allow the `settingsbutton_Callback` function to block until the apply button is clicked.

You might also consider using a handle class for the settings dialog, in which case it could store the settings as properties rather than returning a cell array via `handles.output`.

Comment: As I read uiwait pauses current figure. So how to pause main figure from settings figure?

Comment: What you need to do is prevent the settings callback from returning immediately. So call `uiwait` on a figure handle (pick one) after setting up the settings widgets. Then call `uiresume` from the apply button callback. After `uiwait` returns, read the fields from the relevant widgets, store them in the cell array, and then return them.